command prompt closing immediately i run flutter doctor command
I have a problem with my cmd.When I try to check the state of my installed flutter by running flutter doctor  command ,my cmd closes automatically when I press enter. I have tried solving this issue by clicking the taskbar and ending tasks.It seems it only has this issue when running flutter doctor command since when I run other commands it responds appropriately.
I was expecting a result outputting whether flutter is installed and is okay to run flutter code.

run where flutter dart command and attach the output

make sure you have right path in environment variables, it will look like this make sure container "flutter\bin" at the end
D:\Softwares\flutter\bin


Make sure you have installed git/git bash (Important).

after all restart your PC.

press windows button and run terminal as an administrator and run
flutter doctor


